# Why does the evaluation loss increases when training a huggingface transformers NER model?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

Training a `huggingface transformers` NER model according to the documentation, the evaluation loss increases after a few epochs, but the other scores (accuracy, precision, recall, f1) continuously getting better. The behaviour seems unexpected, is there a simple explanation for this effect? Can this depend on the given data?

[image]

```
model = TokenClassificationModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base', num_labels=len(tag_values))


model.train()
model.zero_grad()

   for epoch in range(epochs):
      for batch in range(batches):
         -- train --
         ...

      train_loss = model.evaluate(train_data)
      validation_loss = model.evaluate(validation_data)
```

Comment: This simply indicated overfitting, a very common phenomenon.

Comment: But shouldn't the other scores then also become worse or at lest remain constant? They improve significantly....

Comment: Can you please use the same axis scale for each diagram? The first diagram has 0.1 steps while all the other diagrams have 0.2 steps.

Comment: Did you come up with any way of dealing with this issue? Dealing with something similar on my transformers model

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy and loss are not necessarily exactly (inversely) correlated.
The loss function is often an approximation of the accuracy function - unlike accuracy, the loss function must be differentiable.
A good explanation can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/341054).